# checkbox is Checked remaining all checkboxes are 'unchecked' in angular js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have multiple checkboxs and these all display by using `ng-repeat`. but one checkbox title is " Custom" by using this... if custom checkbox is checked  remaining all are unchecked and if  remaining all are checked custom checkbox is only unchecked.

```
<ion-checkbox class="card" ng-repeat="(key, value) in packages" ng-model="value.checked" ng-checked="value.checked" ng-change="add(packages)">
    <div class="title">{{value.title}}</div>
        <div class="price-section">{{value.price}}</div>
</ion-checkbox>
```

Comment: We need sample code to help you solving this

Comment: Please post a little of the js code so I can see the title and so on

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check all boxes try something like this.
html:
`<ion-checkbox class="card" ng-repeat="(key, value) in packages" ng-model="value.checked" ng-checked="value.checked" ng-change="add(packages)">
    <div class="title">{{value.title}}</div>
        <div class="price-section">{{value.price}}</div>
</ion-checkbox>`

controller:
`$scope.add = function(item) {
    $scope.boxes = [];
    //push the boxes onto boxes that you want to be selected.
    $scope.value.checked = $scope.boxes
}`

It is hard to explain using your example. Let me show you the code to where I am doing something like this. I have a list of user names. When a user calls the changedDepartment function, it will ask if it wants to select all the users inside the dropdown.

html:

```html
<select ng-model="selectDept" ng-change="changedDepartment(selectDept)" ng-options="option as option.departmentName for option in department" multiple="multiple">
<option value="" disabled>Select a Department/s</option>
</select>
```

controller:

```js
$scope.changedDepartment = function(item) {
   $scope.users = [];
   $scope.selectUser = [];
   if ($scope.department.length > 0) {
   if (item[0].DepartmentUsers.length > 0) {
    $scope.users.length = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < item[i].DepartmentUsers.length; j++) {
        if (profile[0].userProfileID != item[i].DepartmentUsers[j].userProfileID) {
          console.log(item[i].DepartmentUsers[j]);
          $scope.users.push(item[i].DepartmentUsers[j]);
        }
      }
    }
      var confirm = $ionicPopup.confirm({
       title: 'Confirm',
       template: 'Would you like to send to all the users in ' + item[0].departmentName + ' department?',
       cancelText: 'No',
       okText: 'Yes'
     });
     confirm.then(function(res) {
       if (res) {
        $scope.selectUser = $scope.users;
       } else {
        $scope.selectUser = [];
        }
      });
      //item.pop();
      //$scope.changedDepartment(item);
  }
  item = "";
  }
 }
```

ignore the giant for loop. That is just searching my data models for the users and pushing them into $scope.users. The main focus is when it is asked if we want to select all users. It sets the ng-model to the entire array of users we pushed earlier in the loop.

I don't know if this is relevant to your situation since your using check boxes and I was using multiple selection dropdowns, but hopefully it helps some!